# iPhone UISearchBar takes two clicks to be selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a UISearchBar in my app, and I'm running the following code with it:

```
- (void)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

So when the user clicks the search bar, a cancel button pops up next to it.

This, unfortunately, makes it so the text box isn't selected, and the keyboard doesn't pop up.  You have to click the search bar a second time to get those things to happen.

How would I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should be like this:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

The key element is returning YES in this method to indicate that it should in fact begin editing.

Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBarShouldBeginEditing:

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That actually helps me understand iOS SDK a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

could you change your code as below

```
 [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
```

I think your were passing `YES` in the above method.